# Matter.js change colors

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, matter.js

I'm working with matter.js on a small project.

I'm tryin to change the background color of the canvas and add custom colors to objects.

Does anyone know a tutorial or something for styling matter.js

[Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js-demo/#newtonsCradle)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The properties are `body.render.fillStyle`, `body.render.strokeStyle` and `body.render.lineWidth`.

You can pass these to `Body.create(options)` or more likely if you're using a factory e.g.

```
Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, {
    render: {
         fillStyle: 'red',
         strokeStyle: 'blue',
         lineWidth: 3
    }
});
```

You can also use sprites, see [the code](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/demo/js/Demo.js#L1019-L1026)

If you need more rendering control, it's best to clone [Render.js](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/render/Render.js), customise it and pass it into the engine through `Engine.create(element, options)` as `engine.render.controller`.

Comment: How to pass custom colors (like `#ff0000`)? Setting `fillStyle` to `#ff0000` or `rgb(255,0,0)` simply doesn't work.

Comment: @user4180960 Make sure you are setting `render.options.wireframes = false` for your Render-instance.

Answer (score 23):

As @Martti Laine mentioned in a comment, the following code will only work:

```
Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, {
    render: {
         fillStyle: 'red',
         strokeStyle: 'blue',
         lineWidth: 3
    }
});
```

if `render.options.wireframes` is set to `false`.

```
  var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      wireframes: false // <-- important
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent hours trying to style bodies but nothing works until I saw this! `wireframes:false`

Answer (score 10):

Since nobody answers the part of question about

> I'm tryin to change the background color of the canvas [...]

That part is done like this:

```js
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create an engine
const engine = Engine.create();

const render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine,
  options: {
    width: some_width,
    height: some_height,
    wireframes: false,
    background: 'rgb(255,0,0)' // or '#ff0000' or other valid color string
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers show how to make simple color modifications to Matter.js' built-in renderer. These answers are useful, but since the built-in renderer is intended for prototyping only, a general solution to the question hasn't yet been provided.

Matter.js is a physics engine, not a rendering library. It's intended to be a headless backend for any rendering frontend you choose.

I have many posts showing how to use it in a variety of contexts. Taking a skim through these should show that the rendering limitations of MJS appear time and again, and the solution is almost always "don't use the built-in renderer".

General approaches:

- [Rendering with DOM or React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906218/using-matter-js-to-render-to-the-dom-or-react/65354225#65354225)
- [Rendering with P5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624648/matter-query-region-not-returning-any-collisions-even-though-the-bound-is-clearl/70639149#70639149)
- [Rendering with HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68175128/how-to-apply-gradient-fill-to-an-object-in-matter-js/74911063#74911063)

Solutions using the DOM:

- [how to round an image in matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468816/how-to-round-an-image-in-matter-js/72849934#72849934)
- [How to put a video on a body, Matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058841/how-to-put-a-video-on-a-body-matter-js/72850336#72850336)
- [matter.js: is there any way to animate my sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207865/matter-js-is-there-any-way-to-animate-my-sprite/65301374#65301374)
- [Matter.js Text inside a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681437/matter-js-text-inside-a-rectangle/72849141#72849141)

If you're still not convinced, here's an example using canvas and [rough.js](https://github.com/rough-stuff/rough), illustrating that once you go headless, you can pretty much do whatever you want in terms of styles and colors:

```js
const renderRect = ({body, rect, w, h}) => {
  const {x, y} = body.position;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(body.angle);
  ctx.translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);
  r.draw(rect);
  ctx.restore();
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

const r = rough.canvas(canvas);
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();  
const box = {
  w: 40, h: 40,
  body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(150, 0, 40, 40),
  rect: r.generator.rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40, {
    fill: "red",
    fillStyle: "solid",
    roughness: 1.5,
    hachureAngle: 45,
    hachureGap: 7,
    strokeWidth: 2,
  }),
};
const ground = {
  w: 400, h: 120,
  body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    200, 200, 400, 120, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  rect: r.generator.rectangle(0, 0, 400, 120, {
    fill: "green",
    fillStyle: "solid",
    roughness: 1.5,
    strokeWidth: 2,
  }),
};
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
Matter.Composite.add(
  engine.world, [box.body, ground.body, mouseConstraint]
);

(function rerender() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  renderRect(ground);
  renderRect(box);
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
  requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #dda;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/roughjs@4.3.1/bundled/rough.js"></script>
<canvas width="700" height="400"></canvas>
```